# Why is ProcessPoolExecutor not working in my code?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, concurrent.futures

I have the following methods as part of a class:

```
def download_page(self, page: namedtuple):
    r = requests.get(page.link)
    r.raise_for_status()
    with open(f'{page.number}.jpg', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(r.content)

def download_chapter(self, chapter: namedtuple):
    try:
        os.mkdir(chapter.name)
    except FileExistsError:
        print("This folder already exists. It will be overwritten.")
    os.chdir(chapter.name)

    page_list = self.get_pages(chapter.link)

    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
        executor.map(self.download_page, page_list)

    os.chdir('..')
```

The problem is that when I call the download_chapters() function from my main file, all the directories are created but they are empty. The actual images that should be saved when the executor runs are nowhere to be seen. Also, the whole thing ends really fast, so I'm guessing the executor is not working at all. I have other script that uses the ProcessPoolExecutor function in a very similar way and it works as expected, so I have no idea what I'm missing.

Also, if I replace the executor part with this:

```
for _ in page_list:
    self.download_page(_)
```

Everything works properly, so my other functions are doing their job.

Comment: Add some logging so you can see where your code is getting to - maybe need some exceptoipn handling so you get control of perhaps exceptions from the requests call?

Comment: I wouldn't trust that a `chdir()` in the main process is going to reliably affect a worker process.  It might work when the worker is first launched, but if a worker process gets reused (for a page in a different chapter), it's going to retain its current working directory.

Comment: @jasonharper Even if using `chdir` in general is a bad idea, that doesn't matter here – both chdirs are outside the `with` block for the executor. The worker processes will have died and can't be reused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`executor.map()` returns an iterator](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor.map).

You'll need to iterate over it somehow for it to do work; if you don't need the results, just

```
list(executor.map(self.download_page, page_list))
```

to have a list created of the results and subsequently thrown away.

If you don't want to gather that list of `None`s,

```
for _ in executor.map(self.download_page, page_list):
    pass
```

does just as well.